# Why doesn't .NET/C# optimize for tail-call recursion?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, tail-recursion

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340762/which-languages-support-tail-recursion-optimization) about which languages optimize tail recursion. Why C# doesn't optimize tail recursion, whenever possible?

For a concrete case, why isn't this method optimized into a loop ([Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008) 32-bit, if that matters)?:

```
private static void Foo(int i)
{
    if (i == 1000000)
        return;

    if (i % 100 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine(i);

    Foo(i+1);
}
```

Comment: I was reading a book on Data Structures today which bifurcates recursive function into two namely `preemptive` (e.g. factorial algorithm) and `Non-preemptive` (e.g. ackermann's function). The author gave just two examples which I've mentioned without giving a proper reasoning behind this bifurcation. Is this bifurcation same as tail and non-tail recursive functions?

Comment: Useful conversation about it by Jon skeet and Scott Hanselman on 2016
https://youtu.be/H2KkiRbDZyc?t=3302

Comment: @RBT: I think that is different. It refers to the number of recursive calls. Tail calls are about calls that appear in tail position, i.e. the last thing a function does so it returns the result from the callee directly.

Comment: FWIW, 64 bit release builds of .Net Framework 4.8 [does support TCO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29571052). However, this seems to be dropped in Core.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

JIT compilation is a tricky balancing act between not spending too much time doing the compilation phase (thus slowing down short lived applications considerably) vs. not doing enough analysis to keep the application competitive in the long term with a standard ahead-of-time compilation.

Interestingly the [NGen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Image_Generator) compilation steps are not targeted to being more aggressive in their optimizations. I suspect this is because they simply don't want to have bugs where the behaviour is dependent on whether the JIT or NGen was responsible for the machine code.

The [CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) itself does support tail call optimization, but the language-specific compiler must know how to generate the relevant [opcode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/56c08k0k(v=vs.95)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and the JIT must be willing to respect it.
[F#'s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_(programming_language)) fsc will generate the relevant opcodes (though for a simple recursion it may just convert the whole thing into a `while` loop directly). C#'s csc does not.

See [this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davbr/) for some details (quite possibly now out of date given recent JIT changes). Note that the CLR changes for 4.0 [the x86, x64 and ia64 will respect it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/clrcodegeneration/tail-call-improvements-in-net-framework-4).

Comment: See also this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxtoolsdev/thread/67b6d908-8811-430f-bc84-0081f4393336?StatusCode=1 wherein I discover that tail is slower than a regular call.  Eep!

Answer (score 81):

This [Microsoft Connect feedback submission](https://web.archive.org/web/20140724090729/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/166013/c-compiler-should-optimize-tail-calls) should answer your question. It contains an official response from Microsoft, so I'd recommend going by that.

> Thanks for the suggestion. We've
>   considered emiting tail call
>   instructions at a number of points in
>   the development of the C# compiler.
>   However, there are some subtle issues
>   which have pushed us to avoid this so
>   far: 1) There is actually a
>   non-trivial overhead cost to using the
>   .tail instruction in the CLR (it is
>   not just a jump instruction as tail
>   calls ultimately become in many less
>   strict environments such as functional
>   language runtime environments where
>   tail calls are heavily optimized). 2)
>   There are few real C# methods where it
>   would be legal to emit tail calls
>   (other languages encourage coding
>   patterns which have more tail
>   recursion, and many that rely heavily
>   on tail call optimization actually do
>   global re-writing (such as
>   Continuation Passing transformations)
>   to increase the amount of tail
>   recursion). 3) Partly because of 2),
>   cases where C# methods stack overflow
>   due to deep recursion that should have
>   succeeded are fairly rare.
>
> All that said, we continue to look at
>   this, and we may in a future release
>   of the compiler find some patterns
>   where it makes sense to emit .tail
>   instructions.

By the way, as it has been pointed out, it is worth noting that tail recursion *is* optimised on x64.

Comment: You might find this helpful too: http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2008/07/07/recursing-into-linear-tail-and-binary-recursion.aspx

Comment: No prob, glad you find it helpful.

Comment: The link is now fixed.

Answer (score 16):

C# does not optimize for tail-call recursion because that's what F# is for!

For some depth on the conditions that prevent the C# compiler from performing tail-call optimizations, see this article: [JIT CLR tail-call conditions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2007/06/20/tail-call-jit-conditions.aspx).

**Interoperability between C# and F#**

C# and F# interoperate very well, and because the .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR) is designed with this interoperability in mind, each language is designed with optimizations that are specific to its intent and purposes. For an example that shows how easy it is to call F# code from C# code, see [Calling F# code from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478531/call-f-code-from-c-sharp); for an example of calling C# functions from F# code, see [Calling C# functions from F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524242/calling-c-sharp-functions-from-f).

For delegate interoperability, see this article: [Delegate interoperability between F#, C# and Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2843733).

**Theoretical and practical differences between C# and F#**

Here is an article that covers some of the differences and explains the design differences of tail-call recursion between C# and F#: [Generating Tail-Call Opcode in C# and F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864670/generate-tail-call-opcode).

Here is an article with some examples in C#, F#, and C++\CLI: [Adventures in Tail Recursion in C#, F#, and C++\CLI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jomo_fisher/archive/2007/09/19/adventures-in-f-tail-recursion-in-three-languages.aspx)

The main theoretical difference is that C# is designed with loops whereas F# is designed upon principles of Lambda calculus. For a very good book on the principles of Lambda calculus, see this free book: [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs, by Abelson, Sussman, and Sussman](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/).

For a very good introductory article on tail calls in F#, see this article: [Detailed Introduction to Tail Calls in F#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/07/08/tail-calls-in-fsharp.aspx). Finally, here is an article that covers the difference between non-tail recursion and tail-call recursion (in F#): [Tail-recursion vs. non-tail recursion in F sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248091/f-tail-recursive-function-example).

Answer (score 10):

I was recently told that the C# compiler for 64 bit does optimize tail recursion.

C# also implements this. The reason why it is not always applied, is that the rules used to apply tail recursion are very strict.

Comment: The x64 _jitter_ does this, but the C# compiler does not

Comment: thanks for the information. This is white different then what I previously thought.

Comment: Just to clarify these two comments, C# *never* emits the CIL 'tail' opcode, and I believe this is still true in 2017. However, for all languages, that opcode is always advisory only in the sense that the respective jitters (x86, x64) will silently ignore it if sundry conditions are not met (well, no error except possible ***stack overflow***). This explains why you're forced to follow 'tail' with 'ret' -- it's for this case. Meanwhile, the jitters are also free to apply the optimization when there's no 'tail' prefix in the CIL, again as deemed appropriate, and regardless of the .NET language.

Answer (score 4):

I had a happy surprise today :-)

I am reviewing my teaching material for my upcoming course on recursion with C#.
And it seems that finally tail call optimization has made its way into C#.

I am using NET5 with LINQPad 6 (optimization activated).

Here is the Tail call optimizable Factorial function I used:

```
long Factorial(int n, long acc = 1)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return acc;
    return Factorial(n - 1, n * acc);
}
```

And here is the X64 assembly code generated for this function:

[image: Assembly code]

See, there is no `call`, only a `jmp`. The function is agressively optimized as well (no stack frame setup/teardown). Oh Yes!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [trampoline technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)#High-level_programming) for tail-recursive functions in C# (or Java). However, the better solution (if you just care about stack utilization) is to use [this small helper](http://qualityofdata.com/2012/02/03/how-to-run-most-of-the-recursive-functions-iteratively/) method to wrap parts of the same recursive function and make it iterative while keeping the function readable.

Comment: Trampolines are invasive (they are a global change to the calling convention), ~10x slower than proper tail call elimination and they obfuscate all stack trace information making it much harder to debug and profile code

Answer (score 1):

As other answers mentioned, CLR does support tail call optimization and it seems it was under progressive improvements historically. But supporting it in C# has an open `Proposal` issue in the git repository for the design of the C# programming language [Support tail recursion #2544](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2544).

You can find some useful details and info there. For example @jaykrell mentioned

> Let me give what I know.
>
> Sometimes tailcall is a performance win-win. It can save CPU. jmp is
>   cheaper than call/ret It can save stack. Touching less stack makes for
>   better locality.
>
> Sometimes tailcall is a performance loss, stack win.
>   The CLR has a complex mechanism in which to pass more parameters to
>   the callee than the caller recieved. I mean specifically more stack
>   space for parameters. This is slow. But it conserves stack. It will
>   only do this with the tail. prefix.
>
> If the caller parameters are
>   stack-larger than callee parameters, it usually a pretty easy win-win
>   transform. There might be factors like parameter-position changing
>   from managed to integer/float, and generating precise StackMaps and
>   such.
>
> Now, there is another angle, that of algorithms that demand
>   tailcall elimination, for purposes of being able to process
>   arbitrarily large data with fixed/small stack. This is not about
>   performance, but about ability to run at all.

Also let me mention (as extra info), When we are generating a compiled lambda using expression classes in `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace, there is an argument named 'tailCall' that as explained in its comment it is

> A bool that indicates if tail call optimization will be applied when compiling the created expression.

I was not tried it yet, and I am not sure how it can help related to your question, but Probably someone can try it and may be useful in some scenarios:

```cs
var myFuncExpression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func< … >>(body: … , tailCall: true, parameters: … );

var myFunc =  myFuncExpression.Compile();
```