# F# Tail Recursive Function Example

Tags: f#, tail-recursion

I am new to F# and was reading about tail recursive functions and was hoping someone could give me two different implementations of a function foo - one that is tail recursive and one that isn't so that I can better understand the principle.

Comment: Chris Smith has a nice post on it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2008/08/07/understanding-tail-recursion.aspx

Comment: Thanks - his post was great...

Comment: While Tail Recursive works on functions, checkout [CPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) for the same problem related to multiple functions.

Comment: Updated location of Chris Smith's blog post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/archive/blogs/chrsmith/understanding-tail-recursion

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Start with a simple task, like mapping items from 'a to 'b in a list. We want to write a function which has the signature

```
val map: ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list
```

Where

```
map (fun x -> x * 2) [1;2;3;4;5] == [2;4;6;8;10]
```

Start with **non-tail recursive** version:

```
let rec map f = function
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs -> f x::map f xs
```

This isn't tail recursive because function still has work to do after making the recursive call. `::` is syntactic sugar for `List.Cons(f x, map f xs)`.

The function's non-recursive nature might be a little more obvious if I re-wrote the last line as `| x::xs -> let temp = map f xs; f x::temp` -- obviously its doing work after the recursive call.

Use an **accumulator variable** to make it tail recursive:

```
let map f l =
    let rec loop acc = function
        | [] -> List.rev acc
        | x::xs -> loop (f x::acc) xs
    loop [] l
```

Here's we're building up a new list in a variable `acc`. Since the list gets built up in reverse, we need to reverse the output list before giving it back to the user.

If you're in for a little mind warp, you can use **continuation passing** to write the code more succinctly:

```
let map f l =
    let rec loop cont = function
        | [] -> cont []
        | x::xs -> loop ( fun acc -> cont (f x::acc) ) xs
    loop id l
```

Since the call to `loop` and `cont` are the last functions called with no additional work, they're tail-recursive.

This works because the continuation `cont` is captured by a new continuation, which in turn is captured by another, resulting in a sort of tree-like data structure as follows:

```
(fun acc -> (f 1)::acc)
    ((fun acc -> (f 2)::acc)
        ((fun acc -> (f 3)::acc)
            ((fun acc -> (f 4)::acc)
                ((fun acc -> (f 5)::acc)
                    (id [])))))
```

which builds up a list in-order without requiring you to reverse it.

---

For what its worth, start writing functions in non-tail recursive way, they're easier to read and work with.

If you have a big list to go through, use an accumulator variable.

If you can't find a way to use an accumulator in a convenient way and you don't have any other options at your disposal, use continuations. I personally consider non-trivial, heavy use of continuations hard to read.

Comment: In the code immediately below "Continuation Passing" you use the id function without defining it (the line "loop id l".  Am I correct in assuming it'd be (fun x->x)?

Comment: @Onorio Catenacci: `id` is one of the built-in functions which come with F#, and it has the definition `let id x = x`.

Comment: @Juliet--I should have known better than to think you'd miss something so obvious :-)  I just thought you'd neglected to copy all of the demonstration code.

Comment: sorry if I'm being dense but I'm trying to wrap my head around your first accumulator example and I don't understand one bit: you call the recursive function via `loop (f x::acc) xs` however the recursive function only receives one argument, so this wouldn't compile? maybe there's something I don't understand about the **function** keyword which I actually haven't ever used yet (can this use the `fun` keyword instead?)

Comment: @knocte the `function` keyword adds an argument to the function. See https://markhneedham.com/blog/2010/02/07/f-function-keyword/

Comment: I tried your solution with the continuation and it doesn't work: ```let accumulate (func: 'a -> 'b) (input: 'a list): 'b list =    
    let rec loop cont = function        
            | [] -> cont []
            | x::xs -> loop ( fun acc -> cont (func x::acc) ) xs
    loop id input``` with ```[<Fact()>]
let ``Accumulate large data set without stack overflow`` () =
    accumulate id [1..100000]
    |> should equal [1..100000] ```. It doesn't do a tail recursion.

Comment: I use donet 3.1.101 with Jetbrains Rider on macos. I don't know the exact version of f#.

Comment: Just to be clear, when I said "it doesn't work" I meant it doesn't do a tail recursion. The test I included in my comment fails.

Comment: @costa: I just copied your code snippet and tried it. When compiled as `DEBUG`, it overflows the stack, when compiled as `RELEASE`, it doesn't. This is expected, TCO is only on when optimizations are on. This difference can also be observed in FSI (F# Interactive, you can switch TCO off with `--tailcalls-`)

Answer (score 32):

An attempt at a shorter explanation than in the other examples:

```
let rec foo n =
    match n with
    | 0 -> 0
    | _ -> 2 + foo (n-1)

let rec bar acc n =
    match n with
    | 0 -> acc
    | _ -> bar (acc+2) (n-1)
```

Here, `foo` is not tail-recursive, because foo has to call `foo` recursively in order to evaluate `2+foo(n-1)` and return it.

However, `bar` ís tail-recursive, because `bar` doesn't have to use the return value of the recursive call in order to return a value. It can just let the recursively called `bar` return its value immediately (without returning all the way up though the calling stack). The compiler sees this and optimized this by rewriting the recursion into a loop.

Changing the last line in `bar` into something like `| _ -> 2 + (bar (acc+2) (n-1))` would again destroy the function being tail-recursive, since `2 +` leads to an action that needs to be done *after* the recursive call is finished.

Comment: Thanks Batibix for the succint example

Answer (score 11):

Here is a more obvious example, compare it to what you would normally do for a factorial.

```
let factorial n =
    let rec fact n acc =
        match n with
        | 0 -> acc
        | _ -> fact (n-1) (acc*n)
    fact n 1
```

This one is a bit complex, but the idea is that you have an accumulator that keeps a running tally, rather than modifying the return value.

Additionally, this style of wrapping is usually a good idea, that way your caller doesn't need to worry about seeding the accumulator (note that fact is local to the function)

Answer (score 5):

I'm learning F# too.
The following are non-tail recursive and tail recursive function to calculate the fibonacci numbers.

**Non-tail recursive version**

```
let rec fib = function
    | n when n < 2 -> 1
    | n -> fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);;
```

**Tail recursive version**

```
let fib n =
    let rec tfib n1 n2 = function
    | 0 -> n1
    | n -> tfib n2 (n2 + n1) (n - 1)
    tfib 0 1 n;;
```

Note: since the fibanacci number could grow really fast you could replace last line `tfib 0 1 n` to
`tfib 0I 1I n` to take advantage of Numerics.BigInteger Structure in F#

Answer (score 3):

Also, when testing, don't forget that indirect tail recursion (tailcall) is turned off by default when compiling in Debug mode.  This can cause tailcall recursion to overflow the stack in Debug mode but not in Release mode.