# Remove element from list in f#

Tags: f#, tail-recursion, f#-3.0

Suppose I have a sorted list l, with possible duplicate values - and I want to return a list with the value n removed from l, but only once. - eg for inputs [1,2,3,3,3,4] and 3, return [1,2,3,3,4]. How would I do this?

Comment: You mean a `System.Collections.Generic.SortedList` ? Or an (assumed sorted) immutable F# list?

Comment: immutable F# list. I edited the question to make this clearer

Comment: It's still unclear what you are asking - the current wording suggests that you want a function that takes a list `l` and a value `n`, removes value `n` from the list and returns all the other elements of `l` (including potential duplicates of `n`) as an array. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, I've improved the clarity of the question to reflect this. the output should actually be a list (I put array by accident, sorry)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward approach would be something like this:

```
let rec remove n lst = 
    match lst with
    | h::tl when h = n -> tl
    | h::tl -> h :: (remove n tl)
    | []    -> []
```

You recursively traverse the list until you find `n` - if you do, you drop it and return the tail. Note that this isn't tail-recursive, but can be easily made so.

Comment: You could easily use list.fold where accumulator is simple bool. This would make it tail recursive

Comment: @MichalMa: You mean a fold where the accumulator is the output list + the bool flag? That would work, but with fold you would have to traverse the list to the end, which is not necessary. By a simple change I meant introducing an inner function with an accumulator for building the list.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested (I know I was), I came up with a tail-optimized version of the accepted answer using an accumulator since I am new to F# and very rusty with my recursion work.

```
let remove n list =
    let rec removeTail n list acc =
        match list with
        | h::tl when h = n -> List.append (List.rev acc) tl
        | h::tl -> (removeTail n tl (h::acc))
        | [] -> List.rev acc
    removeTail n list []
```

Resources I used:

- [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248477/1346943)
- [MSDN
  Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/07/08/tail-calls-in-fsharp.aspx)

Comment: Looks good, but you want to return the reversed `acc` in empty list case as well.

Comment: @scrwtp thanks, and thanks for the original answer too

Answer (score -1):

Before List.distinct is available, you can use Seq.distinct :

```
let l = [1;1;2;3;3;3;4]
let dl = 
    l
    |> Seq.ofList
    |> Seq.distinct
    |> Seq.toList
```

In F# 4.0, we will have List.distinct as announced [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-a-preview-of-f-4-0-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-vs-2015.aspx) :

*In F# 4.0, the collections API has been fully normalized across Array, List, and Seq.  There are now dedicated, optimized implementations of all common operations for each type, and even a few brand-new functions.  This represents the addition of a whopping 95 APIs in total.*

Comment: This is *not* what the OP was looking for.