# Merge sort for f sharp

Tags: f#, mergesort

This is my code, when I enter a very large number I get stack overflow error does anyone know why? When i enter a very large number i get that error and im not really sure what is causing it, it is only with large numbers small ones work fine.....

```
//
// merge two sorted lists into one:
//
let rec merge L1 L2 = 
  if L1 = [] && L2 = [] then
    []
  else if L1 = [] then
    L2
  else if L2 = [] then
    L1
  else if L1.Head <= L2.Head then
    L1.Head :: merge L1.Tail L2
  else
    L2.Head :: merge L1 L2.Tail

//
// mergesort:
//
let rec mergesort L = 
  match L with
 | []    -> []
 | E::[] -> L
 | _     -> 
   let mid = List.length L / 2
   let (L1, L2) = List.splitAt mid L
   merge (mergesort L1) (mergesort L2)
```

Comment: Put your code in the question, not a link

Comment: Sorry about that i edited the post

Comment: Still not complete - please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Im not sure why you had me read that idk what else isnt complete

Comment: well, when I posted the link the `merge` function was missing, but now it looks ok

Comment: you get a stack overflow exception because your code is not tail-recursive (the last call is `merge`)

Comment: Ok yes thank you i see that, i just dont know the syntax very well being the language is new to me, can you give me a hand?

Answer (score 7):

In both your functions you had the problem, that the last step you take is not the recursive call but some other thing:

- in `merge` it is the `::` operation
- in `mergesort` it is the `merge`

So you have to get to a point where the very last thing is the recursive call!

One possibility in situations where you have more than one recursive call to make is to use **continuations** - the idea is to pass a function around that should be called with the result of the current step and then continue the computation from there.

this is a *tail-recursive* version of `mergesort` using this technique:

```
let mergesort xs = 
    let rec msort xs cont = 
        match xs with
        | []    -> cont []
        | [x]   -> cont xs
        | _     -> 
            let mid = List.length xs / 2
            let (xs', xs'') = List.splitAt mid xs
            msort xs' (fun ys' -> msort xs'' (fun ys'' -> cont (merge ys' ys'')))
    msort xs id
```

as you can see the idea is not to hard - instead of first calling both recursive paths it starts with just one half but adds a continuation that basically says:

> once I have the result of `mergesort xs'` I take the result `ys'` and continue by `mergesort`ing `xs''` and then merge those

of course the second step is done in just the same way (push the `merge` into the continuation)

the very first *continuation* is usually the identity as you can see in the very last line ;)

---

and here is something similar for your `merge`:

```
let merge xs ys = 
    let rec mrg xs ys cont =
        match (xs, ys) with
        | ([], ys) -> cont ys
        | (xs, []) -> cont xs
        | (x::xs', y::ys') ->
            if x < y 
            then mrg xs' ys (fun rs -> cont (x::rs))
            else mrg xs ys' (fun rs -> cont (y::rs))
    mrg xs ys id
```

---

those will of course take as much space on the heap (probably more) - but that is usually no problem - your stack should be fine ;)

Comment: Is there anyway i can make my code use tail recursion, the point of me doing this is to learn that?

Comment: those are! - look where the recursive calls happen - those are always the last thing a evaluation-path inside the function will do

Comment: it's just to **make them tail-recursive**

Comment: So, what im trying to do here is only use matching, pending operator, concatenation, split at function, and tail recursion. So no continuation. Is this even possible?

Comment: I will not say that you cannot find some way with accumulators or something but AFAIK *I don't think there is* (although I can show you no proof right now)

Comment: Well, my professor told use to take it as a challenge is we wanted to try and i was interested, he said there are a few ways to do it, i tried and failed and now want to know how lol

Comment: well the one thing I can show you is how to do it this style - maybe you can find a way using *accumulators* (thinking of it you probably can) but this will get ugly IMO

Comment: PS: it would have helped a lot if you had mentioned that this is some homework - now you lost the opportunity of us leading you to your own solution :(

Comment: Its not homework lol, its a challenge for sun we get nothing for completing it

Comment: that is not what I meant - it's an exercise for you. I have no problem with people asking their homework / exercises but I usually answer differently as the goal should be to learn something instead of getting a quick answer

Comment: where? To understand the continuation?

Comment: I dont want to use continue continuation ); strictly matching, pending operator, concatenation, split at

Comment: good luck ^^ - I would not invest to much time into it though

Answer (score 3):

Each recursive call requires stack space.  The more times mergesort calls itself, the more stack is used.

You avoid the stack overflow with recursive function by taking advantage of [tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248091/f-tail-recursive-function-example).  It simply means the last thing a function does is call itself, the call is removed and turns into a jump instead, saving stack space.

This is tricky to do in your case because you have to call mergesort twice.  Only one of them can be last.  The solution is to use a [continuation](http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2008/08/13/recursing-on-recursion-continuation-passing/).  You only call mergesort once, but pass it a function to call, which will call mergesort the second time.

Search the internet for F# examples of a merge sort that uses continuations.

Comment: Not my code nor do I wish to duplicate the internet here.

Comment: How can i edit my code to use tail recursion, being that the point of this is to learn tail recursion?