# Defining the Accumulator of a Tail Recursive Function in F#

Tags: f#, tail-recursion

I am a beginner in F#, and I am still having trouble wrapping my head around the concept of the tail recursion. Specifically, I do not know how tail recursion works since neither is there any value associated with the accumulator, nor is the accumulator ever defined.

Here is some sample code for a tail recursive function for computing a factorial

```
let factorial x =
// Keep track of both x and an accumulator value (acc)
    let rec tailRecursiveFactorial x acc =
        if x <= 1 then 
            acc
        else 
            tailRecursiveFactorial (x - 1) (acc * x)
    tailRecursiveFactorial x 1
```

I am not asking for how to write a tail recursive function, nor am I asking for examples of tail and non-tail recursive functions. What I am asking is how the accumulator works since it is never defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F# Tail Recursive Function Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248091/f-tail-recursive-function-example)

Comment: @ I am asking how the accumulator works if it is never defined, not for some examples of tail-recursive functions.

Answer (score 9):

The accumulator is defined here:

```
let rec tailRecursiveFactorial x acc =
```

This local function has the type `int -> int -> int`, which means that `acc` has type `int`.

The compiler infers this because `x` is compared to the literal `1`, which is of the type `int`, because it's an unqualified integer literal. This means `x` must be of the type `int` as well.

Likewise, the expression `acc * x` makes use of `x`, and the compiler then infers that `acc` must have the type `int` as well.

Comment: But how does the compiler know what the value of the accumulator is?

Comment: @ClementDecker The value is assigned the literal `1` in the final expression: `tailRecursiveFactorial x 1`.

Comment: @ClementDecker also note you may want to change `x` to `n` in the first line and last line.  As is, you have `x` referring to two different variables (the arg in `factorial` and the first arg to `tailRecursiveFactorial`) and it seems like it may be confusing you.