# More Efficient Recursive Tetranacci function in F#

Tags: f#, time-complexity, fibonacci, c#-to-f#, f#-3.0

I am trying to write a tetranacci function using F# as efficiently as possible the first solution I came up with was really inefficient. can you help me come up with a better one? How would i be able to implement this in linear time?

```
let rec tetra n =
 match n with
 | 0 -> 0
 | 1 -> 1
 | 2 -> 1
 | 3 -> 2
 | _ -> tetra (n - 1) + tetra (n - 2) + tetra (n - 3) + tetra (n - 4)
```

Comment: Have you tried with [tail calls](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/fsharpteam/tail-calls-in-f/)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248091/f-tail-recursive-function-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [tail recursive](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/fsharpteam/tail-calls-in-f/) version, which compiles to mostly loops (and its complexity should be O(n)):

```
let tetr n =
  let rec t acc4 acc3 acc2 acc1 = function
    | n when n = 0 -> acc4
    | n when n = 1 -> acc3
    | n when n = 2 -> acc2
    | n when n = 3 -> acc1
    | n -> t acc3 acc2 acc1 (acc1 + acc2 + acc3 + acc4) (n - 1)
  t 0 1 1 2 n
```

`acc1` corresponds to `tetra (n - 1)`,
`acc2` corresponds to `tetra (n - 2)`,
`acc3` corresponds to `tetra (n - 3)`,
`acc4` corresponds to `tetra (n - 4)`

Based on [the Fibonacci example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Solutions/Recursion)

Answer (score 5):

You could economise by devising a function that computes the state for the next iteration on a 4-tuple. Then the sequence generator function `Seq.unfold` can be used to build a sequence that contains the first element of each state quadruple, an operation that is 'lazy` -- the elements of the sequence are only computed on demand as they are consumed.

```
let tetranacci (a3, a2, a1, a0) = a2, a1, a0, a3 + a2 + a1 + a0
(0, 1, 1, 2) 
|> Seq.unfold (fun (a3, _, _, _ as a30) -> Some(a3, tetranacci a30))
|> Seq.take 10
|> Seq.toList
// val it : int list = [0; 1; 1; 2; 4; 8; 15; 29; 56; 108]
```

Note that the standard Tetranacci sequence ([OEIS A000078](http://oeis.org/A000078)) would usually be generated with the start state of `(0, 0, 0, 1)`:

```
// val it : int list = [0; 0; 0; 1; 1; 2; 4; 8; 15; 29]
```

Answer (score 5):

[kaefer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2807130/kaefer) answer is good, but why stop at linear time?  It turns out that you can actually achieve logarithmic time instead, by noting that the recurrence can be expressed as a matrix multiplication:

```
[T_n+1]   [0; 1; 0; 0][T_n]
[T_n+2] = [0; 0; 1; 0][T_n+1]
[T_n+3]   [0; 0; 0; 1][T_n+2]
[T_n+4]   [1; 1; 1; 1][T_n+3]
```

But then `T_n` can be achieved by applying the recurrence n times, which we can see as the first entry of `M^n*[T_0; T_1; T_2; T_3]` (which is just the upper right entry of `M^n`), and we can perform the matrix multiplication in O(log n) time by repeated squaring:

```
type Mat =
| Mat of bigint[][]
    static member (*)(Mat arr1, Mat arr2) =
        Array.init arr1.Length (fun i -> Array.init arr2.[0].Length (fun j -> Array.sum [| for k in 0 .. arr2.Length - 1 -> arr1.[i].[k]*arr2.[k].[j] |]))
        |> Mat

    static member Pow(m, n) =
        match n with
        | 0 -> 
            let (Mat arr) = m
            Array.init arr.Length (fun i -> Array.init arr.Length (fun j -> if i = j then 1I else 0I))
            |> Mat
        | 1 -> m
        | _ ->
            let m2 = m ** (n/2)
            if n % 2 = 0 then m2 * m2
            else m2 * m2 * m

let tetr =
    let m = Mat [| [|0I; 1I; 0I; 0I|]
                   [|0I; 0I; 1I; 0I|]
                   [|0I; 0I; 0I; 1I|]
                   [|1I; 1I; 1I; 1I|]|]
    fun n -> 
        let (Mat m') = m ** n
        m'.[0].[3]

for i in 0 .. 50 do
    printfn "%A" (tetr i)
```

Comment: Nice answer. Diagonalize to get O(1) time!