# Does C# do tail recursion?

Tags: c#, tail-recursion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't .net/C# eliminate tail recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491376/why-doesnt-net-c-eliminate-tail-recursion)

Does C# do tail recusion?

I can't find any documentation telling me if it does or not.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491376/why-doesnt-net-c-eliminate-tail-recursion

Comment: also this from msdn http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2007/06/20/tail-call-jit-conditions.aspx

Comment: The C# Specification does not mention TCO.

Comment: I believe it to be related more to the compiler than the language

Comment: @V4Vendetta Not so. A compiler (and run-time) just implements a language (perhaps with bugs, extensions, and clever optimizations). Without guarantees provided by the language it is an infuriating exercise to try guess what the compiler/run-time/JIT will do in a given situation (and what it will do in a *slightly different* environment).

Answer (score 14):

C# does not innately support tail recursion in the language but here is an interesting [article](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/04/bouncing-on-your-tail.html) on a similar technique call trampolining that may help you in your situation

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, it does not, at least not yet.

I'm not sure if the standard itself specifies anything about (dis)allowing tail recursion. Regardless, since .Net supports tail recursion, so it would be nice for this to make its way into C#.

If you really need tail recursion in a .Net language, consider F# as an alternative.

Comment: It (.NET) does. Both 32- and 64-bit JITters have done it since CLR 2, but it has been vastly improved in .NET 4.

Comment: I'd still like to know a good reason as to why tail recursion isn't implemented directly in the C# compiler. It seems pretty simple to do (especially considering that tail recursion is native to .Net), and it's a really useful feature that one needs to rely on sometimes (ok, not *needs* per se, but would rather not have to write out a loop instead).

Comment: There's a bit of a weird thing there :) With the 64-bit JITter, it's mostly irrelevant whether or not the compiler emits `tail.` prefixes for its calls. There are only a few cases where it makes a difference (main exception: it matters if you've disabled optimizations), so from the compiler's point of view, it doesn't really matter. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2007/06/20/tail-call-jit-conditions.aspx  I'm not sure what the current behaviour of the 32-bit JITter is but according to the previous article (CLR 2) the compiler had to emit the prefix for it to take effect.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde Tail recursion optimization is just that---an optimization. Optimizing tail calls means the runtime is no longer able to produce correct stack traces (because some stack frames are elided by the optimization). If C# compiler optimized the tail calls, the code would then produce incorrect stack traces. Source: http://gbracha.blogspot.cz/2009/12/chased-by-ones-own-tail.html

Comment: @user7610 Thanks a lot for that reference, I enjoyed reading it. However, it actually contradicts, rather than supports, your statements. You claim that "Optimizing tail calls means the runtime is no longer able to produce correct stack traces", but Bracha showed exactly the opposite. He even says that tail call optimization should be required, and references Guy Steele, who makes the case that tail call optimization is required to fully support object oriented abstraction (I found Steele's article [here](http://www.eighty-twenty.org/2011/10/01/oo-tail-calls/); the original link is dead).

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde He says preserving stack traces and good debugging experience in general is a problem. He then puts forth few ideas for optimizing tail calls while keeping stack traces. Show me a language that actually implements any of it, though. Since there is none, that suggests it is not that simple.

Comment: He is right that tall call optimization should be required, though. In fact, CLR supports tail calls exactly for the reason in his Argument 1 (at tne end of the blog). "For CLR 4 the fact that the x64 JIT would sometimes not honor the “tail.” prefix prevented functional languages like F# from being viable.  So we worked to improve the x64 JIT so that it could honor the “tail.” prefix all of the time and help make F# a success." http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/05/11/tail-call-improvements-in-net-framework-4.aspx