# Minimum value in a Linked List. Incorrect recursive result?

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

Trying to brush up on some concepts. I am trying to find the minimum value present amongst all Nodes in a Linked List implementation. I think for some reason my code is returning all the recursive return values, instead of only the last one. Can somebody check please what looks to be the issue in my findMin method?

```
public class Node
{
    public int data;
    public Node next;
    public Node(int d)
    {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
}



public static int findMin(Node head,int min=0)
{
    if (min == 0)
        min = head.data;
    if (head.data < min)
    {
        min = head.data;
    }
    else
    {
        findmin(head.next, min);
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: Please try using a debugger.

Comment: Not directly related to the question itself, but why use `0`as default for `min`? I assume it should be `int.MaxValue`, since you are attempting to find the smallest element in the list.

Comment: Also, it's not entirely clear what you mean by "I think for some reason my code is returning all the recursive return values, instead of only the last one." Maybe provide an example of what `findMin()` returns for a given list of numbers?

Comment: Is C# car insensitive? Where are you using the result (the possible min value)  returned by `findmin`?

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you are using recursion rather than looping for educational purposes? Because if not, you should not be using recursion to solve this.

Comment: That's true @MatthewWatson, just for self-learning. Also, I agree with other posters that min should not have been init to 0. I had used that as a quick check against my test input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's going to return you the first element. Or sometimes crash.

```
if (min == 0) min = head.data; //true initially. min=first element
if (head.data < min) //false. We just assigned it, it does not get executed
{
    min = head.data;
}
else
{
    findmin(head.next, min); //this gets executed but result is ignored
}
return min; // return head.data that you assigned in the first line
```

This is very broken.

1. you forgot to assign result of findmin(head.next, min) to
   anything
2. Even if head.data < min you still need to check the rest of the
   list. So "else" is not required
3. you forgot to check if list is empty
4. initial value should be int.MaxValue. Not 0, and not 10000 as
   suggested above. Then you don't need this extra comparison (because
   anything is less than 100000)
5. It's better to put recursive call on the end to let compiler (or JIT)
   replace tail-recursion with a loop. Or just write a loop yourself.

Here's what it should be

```
public static int findMin(Node head,int min=int.MaxValue)
{
     if (head == null) return min;
     if (head.data < min) min = head.data;
     return findmin(head.next, min);
}
```

Comment: is C# tail-call optimised? In any case this should be the accepted answer :P

Comment: I assumed it did but I was wrong. According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102520/does-c-sharp-do-tail-recursion

compiler does not do it but JIT optimizes these calls.

Comment: This worked. I now see the basic flaws in my implementation. Thanks!

Comment: @yu_sha, in your example code, what happens when head.data is not less than min? In that case there is nothing to return I think for the findmin method, so won't that be a problem sometimes?

Comment: Initially min is set to the default parameter value of int.MaxValue. If list is empty this is what gets returned. 

If list is not empty the first element is going to be less (or equal) to int.MaxValue.

Answer (score 1):

The response of the recursive call of `findmin` never gets assigned to min. So calling it like `min = findmin(head.next, min);` should fix your problem

Comment: that's not going to fix the issue, there is a logic error, where recursion stops once a value less than `min` is found. Not to mention that `min` is initialised as zero.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues: 
1. passing the `min` by value 
2. `min` initialized as `0`.

Try this instead

```
public static int findMin(Node cur) {
    if (cur == null) return 1000000;
    int next_min = findMin(cur.next)
    if (cur.data < next_min) return cur.data;
    return next_min;
}
```

Better to not use recursion here to save `stack` memory. Just use `while` loop and find the minimum.