# Is it possible to implement an infinite IEnumerable without using yield with only C# code?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, infinite-loop

**Edit**: Apparently off topic...moving to [Programmers.StackExchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/216750/is-it-possible-to-implement-an-infinite-ienumerable-without-using-yield-with-onl).

This isn't a practical problem, it's more of a riddle.

## Problem

I'm curious to know if there's a way to implement something equivalent to the following, but without using `yield`:

```
IEnumerable<T> Infinite<T>()
{
    while (true) { yield return default(T); }
}
```

## Rules

1. You can't use the `yield` keyword
2. Use only C# itself directly - no IL code, no constructing dynamic assemblies etc.
3. You can only use the basic .NET lib (only `mscorlib.dll`, `System.Core.dll`? not sure what else to include). However if you find a solution with some of the other .NET assemblies (WPF?!), I'm also interested.
4. Don't implement IEnumerable or IEnumerator.

## Notes

The closest I've come yet:

```
IEnumerable<int> infinite = null;
infinite = new int[1].SelectMany(x => new int[1].Concat(infinite));
```

This is "correct" but hits a StackOverflowException after 14399 iterations through the enumerable (not quite infinite).

I'm thinking there might be no way to do this due to the CLR's [lack of tail recursion optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491376/why-doesnt-net-c-optimize-for-tail-call-recursion). A proof would be nice :)

Comment: Why?  yield is a perfectly good option for this, why would you want to tie your hands like that?

Comment: Second, as there is a perfectly valid way to accomplish the task, namely `yield`.  This question does not belong on SO.  You might try Programmers.SE or CodeReview.SE.

Comment: @Dan-o: I bet it's one of that silly work interviewers who ask weird questions - asked sinelaw such a question on an interview, so now he is curious of what he would answer :-)

Comment: Of course you can. It's just a matter of implementing `IEnumerator<T>` and having `MoveNext()` always return true (and hopefully provide a meaningful `Current` value).

Comment: Whose riddle is this? And, have you considered writing a custom `class`, such as one implementing [`IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx)?

Comment: @Trillian, of course. That should have been in the "no" rules.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, it's mine (or nobody's) riddle, I was just fiddling with infinite enumerables and got curious.

Comment: You need something that is an `IEnumerable<T>` ... so make a class ... implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @ta.speot.is, yip, updated the rules to not allow that :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a riddle and answer site.

Comment: So, "implement infinite IEnumerable without implementing IEnumerable"?

Comment: @ta.speot.is, ok - added the [same question on Programmers.StackExchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/216750/is-it-possible-to-implement-an-infinite-ienumerable-without-using-yield-with-onl).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming in general and not a specific question.


Answer (score 5):

1. Take the `yield` example from your question and dump it into Visual Studio.
2. Compile.
3. Open in Reflector/ILSpy/dotPeek/etc. and display decompiled sources in C# 1.0 language level (or switch on display of compiler generated sources).
4. Declare victory, eat cake.

Comment: That *would* be interesting - thanks, checking now

Comment: Ok, according to the IL code the compiler generates an anonymous class that implements IEnumerable, so that's that. Interesting to know, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a practically infinite iterator:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var infiniteIterator =
            Enumerable.Range(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue)
                      .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Range(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue))
                      .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Range(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue))
                      .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Range(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue))
                      .Select(i => default(int));

        foreach (var infinite in infiniteIterator)
            Console.WriteLine(infinite);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it is. That's about (2^32)^4 = 2^128 iterations I think. Still not infinite though :)

Comment: I believe the time will end before this thing does (if I'm mistaken add some more `SelectMany` calls), so if your definition of infinite covers a period where time has no definition then sure, it's not infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Use of `IEnumerable<T>` and `yield` invokes some C# compiler magic where it wraps the logic into an implementation of `IEnumerable`, like so:

```
IEnumerable<T> Infinite<T>() {
    return new Buzzlightyear<T>();
}
private class BuzzLightyear<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : new() {
    public Boolean MoveNext() { return true; }
    public T Current { return new T(); }
}
```

Comment: You're right, but I forgot to mention that this is one of the ways I'm trying to do without. Added as rule #4

Comment: maybe you meant `BuzzLightyear<T> : IEnumerator<T>`?

Comment: You haven't implemented `IEnumerable<T>`. Look at MSDN.

Comment: "I'm trying to do without" - what is the aim for that?