# Using return in recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

```
public static int Mystery(int a,int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return 0;
    if (b % 2 == 0) 
    { 
        return Mystery(a + a, b / 2); 
    }
    else
    {
        return Mystery(a + a, b / 2) + a;
    }
}
```

Hello guys can you please tell me what's the difference between using a return Mystery(a +a ...etc) and calling it simply by using Mystery(a + a)? 
What I have been thinking till now is that when I use return something it actually creates a way back for the recursion to come back and using recursion without return (ex.Mystery( a + a etc..)) goes only in depth without actually leaving any path to go back.
Thanks!

Comment: The function is supposed to return an int, if you don't return an int it's a compile error...

Comment: If you just have a recursive function call, when the call returns it will continue execution at the next line. When you use `return` with a function call, you often *add* something to *accumulate* a result and return that immediately.

Comment: Well I could juts write return 0 in the end ?! Why should I write return on the recursive call,this is what my question is,it is not about the function that I posted itself.

Comment: you would return if you want the accumulation of all the recursive calls. otherwise why have a recursive call unless it is going to manipulate a class level variable.

Comment: @Bart Thank you that was what I was trying to get it &&  crashmstr thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t return the value from the recursive call, there is no way for you to accumulate the results from all calls. E.g., you are doing `Mystery(…) + a`, so if `Mystery` didn’t return a value there, you would be adding `a` to nothing (and not return that either).

Of course you could also do the recursive call first, save that value and return it later:

```
int value = Mystery(a + a, b / 2);
// …
return value + a;
```

The point is that each recursive call needs to return a value which is processed by the parent call, so that you actually *utilize* the calls.

And finally, you usually would want to have the recursive call on a `return` because there are languages that can remove [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). C# [doesn’t do that though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491376/why-doesnt-net-c-optimize-for-tail-call-recursion).