# Stack overflow exception when using pipes in tail-recursive function

Tags: f#, tail-recursion

I have a naive implementation of a gameloop

```
let gameLoop gamestate =     
    let rec innerLoop prev gamestate =
        let now = getTicks()
        let delta = now - prev
        gamestate 
        |> readInput delta
        |> update delta
        |> render delta
        |> innerLoop delta             

    innerLoop 0L gamestate
```

This implementation throws a stackoverflowexception. In my mind this should be tail recursive. I could make a work around like this

```
let gameLoop gamestate =     
    let rec innerLoop prev gamestate =
        let now = getTicks()
        let delta = now - prev
        let newState = gamestate 
            |> readInput delta
            |> update delta
            |> render delta

        innerLoop now newState

    innerLoop 0L gamestate
```

So my question is why the first code example throws a stackoverflow exception.

Comment: On which platform are you running?

Comment: To clarify: does the work-around version you posted work OK?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I am running on Windows 10 using fsi version 14.0.23413.0

Comment: @Peter yes my workaround is working.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722526/can-does-the-forward-pipe-operator-prevent-tail-call-optimization/35729493) might be of interest here. In any case, it may be interesting if the error happens on a debug or release compile, and whether it matters if a debugger is attached.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is the same as in the thread [Vandroiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4191347/vandroiy) links: when you have

```
a
|> f b
```

then in debug mode the compiler may compile this like a very literal interpretation of

```
(f b) a
```

and explicitly calculate `f b` in one step and apply it to `a` in a second step.  The call with argument `a` is still a tail call, but if the compiler doesn't emit the `tail.` opcode prefix (because tailcalls are turned off, as they are by default in debug mode), then you'll grow the stack with the explicit call and eventually get a stack overflow.

On the other hand, if you write

```
f b a
```

directly then this doesn't happen: the compiler does not partially apply `f`, and instead will recognize that this is a direct recursive call and optimize it into a loop (even in debug mode).

Comment: I think I will go with this awnser. It is most upvoted, it makes sens to me and I can reproduce it in visual studio.

Answer (score 5):

I *think* this is the explanation, though I encourage F# compiler experts to weigh in if I'm off-base:

The first example is not tail-recursive because the expression in tail position is a call to `|>`, not a call to `innerLoop`.

Recalling that `|>` is defined as

```
let (|>) x f = f x
```

if we desugar the pipeline syntax a little bit, when you call

```
gamestate 
    |> readInput delta
    |> update delta
    |> render delta
    |> innerLoop delta
```

you're effectively calling:

```
|> (innerLoop delta) (|> (render delta) (|> (update delta) (|> (readInput delta) gamestate)))
```

as your body expression in the recursive function.

The infix notation obscures this a bit, making it look like `innerLoop` is in tail position.

Comment: Wow, @Vandroiy, that is a monstrous question/answer thread. And it's quite hard to parse it for conclusions, other than -- like you say --  a pipeline can mess with TCO.

Comment: Yeah, but `innerLoop delta` is in the tail position of `|>`, no? So `innerLoop` should tailcall `|>`, which should then tailcall `innerLoop` back or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I deleted my comment just before it was responded to. For clarity, the deleted comment was linking to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722526/can-does-the-forward-pipe-operator-prevent-tail-call-optimization/35729493), which I've now also posted in the question's comments.

Comment: Note that the actual definition is `let inline (|>) x f = f x` (see [prim-types.fs](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs)).  Since the definition is `inline` there shouldn't be a call to the operator in the output at all.

Comment: @sepp2k (Questions of `|>` being inline aside) I don't think the F# compiler is sophisticated enough to infer that a call to a different function in tail position involves a call to the enclosing function and to then optimize it. Different compilers do different things of course: compilers for some languages allow tail-recursion _modulo_ cons, for instance. Tail call rules for F# are detailed at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fsharpteam/2011/07/08/tail-calls-in-f/

Comment: @Peter I'm not talking about the F# compiler detecting that |> calls innerLoop back. I'm talking about it generating a tailcall instruction instead of a call instruction because the call to |> is a tail call.