# C# Recursive function approach?

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a recursive function in a windows service. This function upon completion rewinds itself as it has been repeated multiple times in recursion. Isn't that an overhead ?

Is there any way to avoid unwinding ? Is there any better approach?

Edit : In this method, I get 100 records from DB and then process them and then get another 100 and so on till all the records in DB have been processed.

Also, there is no limit of how many total records there might be in the db so this function can repeat itself quite a lot.

```
public void ServiceFunctionality()
{
    try
    {
        // Get Data From WEBAPI
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = response = client.GetAsync("webapi url link").Result;
        Response<ServiceWrapper> objResponse = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Response<ServiceWrapper>>().Result;

        if (objResponse != null)
        {
            if (objResponse.isSuccess == true)
            {
                listContact = objResponse.data.lContact;
                int MaxPKinSelectedRecords = objResponse.data.MaxPKinSelectedRecords;
                int MaxPKinTotalRecords = objResponse.data.MaxPKinTotalRecords;

                if (listContact != null && listContact.Count>0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Parallel.ForEach(listContact, contact =>
                        {
                            // some code...
                        });
                        // Recursive Call
                        if (MaxPKinTotalRecords != MaxPKinSelectedRecords)
                        {
                            ServiceFunctionality();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Logging
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Logging
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Logging
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Logging
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can make it tail-recursive, the compiler might make it more efficient.  Or you could try to push some of the exception handling outside the recursion.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".  If you really think it's a problem, run some tests timing the execution of your method.  If your tests indicate it's a problem, then optimize.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - not in C# I'm afraid :( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491376/why-doesnt-net-c-optimize-for-tail-call-recursion

Comment: Can you use a while loop instead?

Comment: As an aside, I see no real need for recursion here. A simple loop would probably be better and prevent potential stack overflows.

Comment: [Every recursion can be converted to a loop.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931762/can-every-recursion-be-converted-into-iteration)

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer that knife cuts both ways, of course. "I see no need for looping here. If this won't overflow, simple recursion would probably be better"

Comment: @Martijn: Yes, possibly, but IMHO a loop would be far more readable and easier to understand in this case too.

Comment: Thats rather subjective though. Personally, I tend to find recursive code easier to read, but generally write iteratively when needed as an optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always unwind to a while loop. Because your calls aren't altering state, this is trival.

```
public void ServiceFunctionality()
{
    bool done = false;
    while(!done) {
    try
    {
        done = true; //if we don't reset this, we're done.
        // Get Data From WEBAPI
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = response = client.GetAsync("webapi url link").Result;
        Response<ServiceWrapper> objResponse = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Response<ServiceWrapper>>().Result;

        if (objResponse != null)
        {
            if (objResponse.isSuccess == true)
            {
                listContact = objResponse.data.lContact;
                int MaxPKinSelectedRecords = objResponse.data.MaxPKinSelectedRecords;
                int MaxPKinTotalRecords = objResponse.data.MaxPKinTotalRecords;

                if (listContact != null && listContact.Count>0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Parallel.ForEach(listContact, contact =>
                        {
                            // some code...
                        });
                        // set loop variable
                        if (MaxPKinTotalRecords != MaxPKinSelectedRecords)
                        {
                            done = false;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Logging
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Logging
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Logging
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Logging
    }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use recursion for calling a function whenever you have alternate suitable solution. I personally almost never do

I have tried to keep it same other than using a while..

Do not forget to break your loop. I tried to handle this thing but still

**Just to be very careful, never take a risk of infinite loop on server** I took `maxPossibleIterations`. So that in case of any mistake your web service server would not have to go for infinite iterations

```
public void ServiceFunctionality()
{
    long maxPossibleIterations = 999999;
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
        maxPossibleIterations++;
        // Get Data From WEBAPI
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = response = client.GetAsync("webapi url link").Result;
        Response<ServiceWrapper> objResponse = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Response<ServiceWrapper>>().Result;

        if (objResponse != null)
        {
            if (objResponse.isSuccess == true)
            {
                listContact = objResponse.data.lContact;
                int MaxPKinSelectedRecords = objResponse.data.MaxPKinSelectedRecords;
                int MaxPKinTotalRecords = objResponse.data.MaxPKinTotalRecords;

                if (listContact != null && listContact.Count>0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Parallel.ForEach(listContact, contact =>
                        {
                            // some code...
                        });
                        if (MaxPKinTotalRecords == MaxPKinSelectedRecords)
                        {
                            break;
                        }                        
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Logging
                    }
                }
                else
                    break; //Important
            }
            else
            {
                // Logging
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Logging
            break;
        }
        } // End while
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Logging
    }
}
```