# How to flatten tree

Tags: c#, list, tree

I have a nested list that contains

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Person> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

The list can be used like:

```
var Persons = new List<Person>();
Persons.Add(new Person("Eric"));
Persons[0].Childs = new List<Person>();
Persons[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Tom"));
Persons[0].Childs.Add(new Person("John"));
Persons[0].Childs[0].Childs = new List<Person>();
Persons[0].Childs[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Bill"));
Persons.Add(new Person("John");
```

How can I flatten this tree (put all nodes and sub-nodes, and sub-sub-nodes in a List), e.g. I want to display all children and parents on the same level, with a level Parameter. That means:

Before:

```
-Eric
    -Tom
    -John
        -Bill
```

What I want:

```
-Eric, Level1
-Tom, Level2
-John, Level2
-Bill, Level3
```

Comment: Why didn't nested for loops work for you? also you might want to look at recursion, however my thinking for you is to keep it simple for now, and just bang away at some for loops

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perfect use case for a recursive method

```
public static void DisplayPerson(List<Person> persons, int level = 0)
{
    if (persons != null)
    {
        level++;
        foreach (Person item in persons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-" + item.Name + ", Level" + level); 
            DisplayPerson(item.Childs, level);
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/2J9F5K

Comment: Using recursive methods in cases like this [can cause overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491376/why-doesnt-net-c-optimize-for-tail-call-recursion/23349238). Use [`Stack`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55020774/1275774) instead for these cases.

Answer (score 2):

Perfect use case for the `Stack` class.

```
public static void DisplayPerson(List<Person> persons)
{
    if (persons != null)
    {
        Stack<Person> personStack = new Stack<Person>();
        int level = 1;
        persons.ForEach(personStack.Push);
        while (personStack.Count > 0)
        {
            Person item = personStack.Pop();
            Console.WriteLine("-" + item.Name + ", Level:" + level); 
            if (item.Childs != null)
            {
                item.Childs.ForEach(personStack.Push);
                level++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/eD2GmY

---

Stack is way faster than a recursive method in C# and consumes way less memory, and you can avoid StackOverflows that sometimes are caused by [recursive C# methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491376/why-doesnt-net-c-optimize-for-tail-call-recursion/23349238) used like in @fubo's answer.

Recursive methods are only supposed to recurse once or twice. For use cases like this, with maybe thousands of items, you should use `Stack` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Very short code to flatten a tree without changing the original model:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var flattedTree=new List<Person>();
    var Persons = new List<Person>();
    Persons.Add(new Person("Eric"));
    Persons[0].Childs = new List<Person>();
    Persons[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Tom"));
    Persons[0].Childs.Add(new Person("John"));
    Persons[0].Childs[0].Childs = new List<Person>();
    Persons[0].Childs[0].Childs.Add(new Person("Bill"));
    Persons.Add(new Person("John"));
    Flatten(Persons, flattedTree);
    //flattedTree variable is the flatted model of tree.
}
 static void Flatten(List<Person> nodes, List<Person> flattedNodes)
        {
            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                flattedNodes.Add(node);
                if (node.Childs?.Count > 0)
                    Flatten(node.Childs, flattedNodes);
            }
        }
```