# Changing my iterative selection sort into a recursive sort using C#

Tags: c#, sorting, recursion

I've tried changing my sort into a recursive function where the method calls itself. At least that's my understanding of recursion to forego `for` loops and the method calls itself to repeat the necessary iterations.

Below is my iterative verion:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Integers.Count; i++) //loops through all the numbers
{
    min = i; //setting the current index number to be the minimum

    for (int index = i + 1; index < Integers.Count; index++) //finds and checks pos of min value 
    {                                                        //and switches it with last element using the swap method
        if ((int) Integers[index] > (int) Integers[min]) {
            min = index;
        }
        comparisons++;
    }
    if (i != min) //if statement for if swop is done
    {
        Swap(i, min, Integers, ref swops); //swap method called
    }
    //Swap method called
}
```

I've tried making it recursive. I read online that it was OK to still have `for` loops in a recursive funtion which I guess is not true. I just havent been able to develop a working sort. Am I going to need to split the method into 2 where one method traverses a list and the other does the sort?

Here's my selection sort recursive method attempt below:

```
static void DoSelectionSortRecursive(ArrayList Integers, int i, int swops, int comparisons) {

    int min;
    min = i;
    for (int index = i + 1; index < Integers.Count; index++) //read online that the use of arraylists are deprecated, and i shoudlve rather used List<int> in order to remedy the code. is it necassary 
    {

        if ((int) Integers[index] > (int) Integers[min]) {
            min = index;
        }
        comparisons++;
    }
    if (i != min) {
        Swap(i, min, Integers, ref swops);
    }
    DoSelectionSortRecursive(Integers, (i + 1), comparisons, swops); //DoSelectionSortRecursive method called 
}
```

This is my imporved attempt including performance measures and everything. The original list of integers in the unsorted lists. 84,24,13,10,37.
and im getting 84,24,13,37,10. clearly not in a sorted descending order.
below is the improved code

```
static void DoSelectionSortRecursive(ArrayList Integers)
    {

        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        int shifts = 0;
        int swops = 0;
        int comparisons = 0;

        Sort(Integers, 1,ref swops,ref comparisons);   

        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Selection Sort Recursive: ");
        Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine(swops);
        Console.WriteLine(comparisons);
        Console.WriteLine(shifts);      //not needed in this sort
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");
        foreach (int i in Integers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

    }

    static void Sort(ArrayList Integers, int i, ref int swops, ref int comparisons)
    {
        int min = i;
        int index = i + 1;
        if (index < Integers.Count)        //read online that the use of arraylists are deprecated, and i shoudlve rather used List<int> in order to remedy the code. is it necassary 
        {

            if ((int)Integers[index] > (int)Integers[min])
            {
                min = index;
            }
            comparisons++;
            index++;
        }
        if (i != min)
        {
            Swap(i, min, Integers, ref swops);
        }
        if (i < Integers.Count - 1)
        {
            Sort(Integers, (i + 1), ref comparisons, ref swops);     //DoSelectionSortRecursive method called 
        }

    }

 static void Swap(int x, int y, ArrayList Integers, ref int swap)      //swap method, swaps the position of 2 elements
    {
        swap++;
        int temporary = (int)Integers[x];                   //essentially will swap the min with the current position
        Integers[x] = Integers[y];
        Integers[y] = temporary;
    }
```

Comment: Why bother with recursive when you already have iterative?

Comment: I agree with aybe, unless you are “learning” about recursion, it makes little sense to use a recursive approach when an iterative approach is available. If this for learning, then you should be aware that your current recursive approach should work from my tests, HOWEVER, the code is missing one very important aspect to recursion… _”WHERE is your BASE CASE”_? In the posted code the last line is ALWAYS going to recursively call the method. This is an infinite loop among other problems.

Comment: The code is missing the “Base Case” where you decide if you need to call the method again or quit. So it would appear that the base case would be when the incoming index `i` is equal to the last index in the list of integers. In other words, if `i` is the last index in the list, then we are done. This is the base case and you need to check this or the code will run forever. So, wrap the code to call the method again in an `if` statement like… `if (i < Integers.Count - 1) { // call the method again };` … otherwise exit.

Comment: I tried debugging the code, im learning about recursion, so i have to figure this out. I have to sort integers in descending order as well as include performance measures. so in the code i showed in the question i just removed the code for my performance measure and was facing stack overflow exception issues. I fixed the base case  issue and enclosed it in the if statement. My lecturer said its not recursive because of the for loop. So im assuming in order to avoid stack overflow as well as make it recursive, i split the method into 2. i can post my full  recursive attempt if it helps

Comment: _”My lecturer said its not recursive because of the for loop.”_ … this is not correct. You can have a for loop in a recursive method. Having a for loop in a method does NOT make it a NON-recursive method. Either the instructor is wrong or you are confused. In my test, simply adding the base case to the current code solved the stack overflow. If you want to change to descending, then simply change the “>“ to “<”.

Comment: Ok so i fixed the base case, split the method in which one finds the min, and sorts the list and another method that calls the sort method and has the performance measures. but its not sorting correctly. Its skipping variables. may i edit my original code to showcase

Comment: ive added my imporved code. but the sorting isnt quite right.  on a previous attempt she hilited my for loop and simply commented not recursive so  i assumed. But if i can add the for loop can i not simply add the outer for loop from my iterative version, or will that not fix the sorting

Comment: Where is the `Swap` method?

Comment: Just added it .

Answer (score 1):

There are no "rules" about recursion that say you cannot use loops in the recursive method body. The only rule in recursion is that the function has to call itself, which your second code snippet does, so `DoSelectionSortRecursive` is legitimately recursive.

For example, [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) uses recursion for splitting the array and loops for merging the sorted subarrays. It'd be wrong to call it anything but a recursive function, and it'd be somewhat silly to implement the merging stage (an implementation detail of merge sort) recursively -- it'd be slower and harder to reason about, so loops are the natural choice.

On the other hand, the splitting part of merge sort makes sense to write recursively because it chops the problem space down by a logarithmic factor and has multiple branches. The repeated halving means it won't need to make more than a few or a dozen recursive calls on a typical array. These calls don't incur much overhead and fit well within the call stack.

On the other hand, the call stack can easily blow for linear recursive algorithms in languages [without tail-call optimization like C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491376/why-doesnt-net-c-optimize-for-tail-call-recursion) where each index in the linear structure requires a whole stack frame.

Rules prohibiting loops are concoted by educators who are trying to teach recursion by forcing you to use a specific approach in your solution. It's up to your instructor to determine whether one or both loops need to be converted to recursion for it to "count" as far as the course is concerned. *(apologies if my assumptions about your educational arrangement are incorrect)*

All that is to say that this requirement to write a nested-loop sort recursively is basically a misapplication of recursion for pedagogical purposes. In the "real world", you'd just write it iteratively and be done with it, as [Google does](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/b098168a2b93faf704f1db70533635e601ee0614/src/js/array.js#L294) in the V8 JavaScript engine, which [uses insertion sort on small arrays](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/b098168a2b93faf704f1db70533635e601ee0614/src/js/array.js#L331). I suspect there are many other cases, but this is the one I'm most readily familiar with.

The point with using simple, nested loop sorts in performance-sensitive production code is that they're *not* recursive. These sorts' advantage is that they avoid allocating stack frames and incurring function call overhead to sort small arrays of a dozen numbers where the quadratic time complexity isn't a significant factor. When the array is mostly sorted, insertion sort in particular doesn't have to do much work and is mostly a linear walk over the array (sometimes a drawback in certain real-time applications that need predictable performance, in which case selection sort might be preferable -- see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Comparison_to_other_sorting_algorithms)).

---

Regarding `ArrayList`s, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-5.0) say: "We don't recommend that you use the `ArrayList` class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic `List<T>` class." So you can basically forget about `ArrayList` unless you're doing legacy code (Note: Java *does* use `ArrayList`s which are more akin to the C# `List`. `std::list` isn't an array in C++, so it can be confusing to keep all of this straight).

---

It's commendable that you've written your sort iteratively first, then translated to recursion on the outer loop only. It's good to start with what you know and get something working, then gradually transform it to meet the new requirements.

Zooming out a bit, we can isolate the role this inner loop plays when we pull it out as a function, then write and test it independent of the selection sort we hope to use it in. After the subroutine works on its own, then selection sort can use it as a black box and the overall design is verifiable and modular.

More specifically, the role of this inner loop is to find the minimum value beginning at an index: `int IndexOfMin(List<int> lst, int i = 0)`. The contract is that it'll throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` error if the precondition `0 <= i < lst.Count` is violated.

I skipped the metrics variables for simplicity but added a random test harness that gives a pretty reasonable validation against the built-in sort.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Sorter
{
    private static void Swap(List<int> lst, int i, int j)
    {
        int temp = lst[i];
        lst[i] = lst[j];
        lst[j] = temp;
    }

    private static int IndexOfMin(List<int> lst, int i = 0)
    {
        if (i < 0 || i >= lst.Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        else if (i == lst.Count - 1)
        {
            return i;
        }

        int bestIndex = IndexOfMin(lst, i + 1);
        return lst[bestIndex] < lst[i] ? bestIndex : i;
    }
    
    public static void SelectionSort(List<int> lst, int i = 0)
    {
        if (i < lst.Count)
        {
            Swap(lst, i, IndexOfMin(lst, i));
            SelectionSort(lst, i + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        int tests = 1000;
        int lstSize = 100;
        int randMax = 1000;

        for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++)
        {
            var lst = new List<int>();

            for (int j = 0; j < lstSize; j++)
            {
                lst.Add(rand.Next(randMax));
            }

            var actual = new List<int>(lst);
            SelectionSort(actual);
            lst.Sort();

            if (!lst.SequenceEqual(actual))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FAIL:");
                Console.WriteLine($"Expected => {String.Join(",", lst)}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Actual   => {String.Join(",", actual)}\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a more generalized solution that uses generics and `CompareTo` so that you can sort any list of objects that implement the `IComparable` interface. This functionality is more akin to the built-in sort.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Sorter
{
    public static void Swap<T>(List<T> lst, int i, int j)
    {
        T temp = lst[i];
        lst[i] = lst[j];
        lst[j] = temp;
    }

    public static int IndexOfMin<T>(List<T> lst, int i = 0)
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (i < 0 || i >= lst.Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        else if (i == lst.Count - 1)
        {
            return i;
        }

        int bestIndex = IndexOfMin(lst, i + 1);
        return lst[bestIndex].CompareTo(lst[i]) < 0 ? bestIndex : i;
    }
    
    public static void SelectionSort<T>(List<T> lst, int i = 0)
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (i < lst.Count)
        {
            Swap(lst, i, IndexOfMin(lst, i));
            SelectionSort(lst, i + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        // same as above
    }
}
```

Since you asked how to smush both of the recursive functions into one, it's possible by keeping track of both `i` and `j` indices in the parameter list and adding a branch to figure out whether to deal with the inner or outer loop on a frame. For example:

```cs
public static void SelectionSort<T>(
    List<T> lst, 
    int i = 0, 
    int j = 0, 
    int minJ = 0
) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if (i >= lst.Count)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (j < lst.Count)
    {
        minJ = lst[minJ].CompareTo(lst[j]) < 0 ? minJ : j;
        SelectionSort(lst, i, j + 1, minJ);
    }
    else
    {
        Swap(lst, i, minJ);
        SelectionSort(lst, i + 1, i + 1, i + 1);
    }
}
```

All of the code shown in this post is not suitable for production -- the point is to illustrate what *not* to do.

Comment: Than this has been most insightful. My code is all based on arraylists. i know use of arraylists is deprecated, but its kind of late now. This code is involved in a bigger set of code where i code 4 sorting algorithms and such. That being said is there no way to fix my last improved attempt. My code runs, its just not sorting quite right, and i see that its most likely due to the outer loop

Comment: No problem, happy to help. If your instructor allows `ArrayList`s, that's fine. Yes, the multi-sort comparison-style assignment is a pretty common algorithms assignment. Your final attempt seems like it's trying to smush the outer loop and the inner loop into one recursive function. If you really want to go that route, it could probably be done by passing loop counter state for both the inner and outer loops as indices `i` and `j`, then conditionally incrementing `i` only when `j` reaches the end of the list. As my post suggests, splitting out the inner loop as its own subroutine is easier.