# In C# coroutine is it possible to combine a yield return first of item with forward to another IEnumerable for rest of items?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, coroutine

I'm writing a Markov-chain following recursive function, and what I want to do is `yield` the head item but then forward to or return a different IEnumerable object for the rest of the values.

Basically I'm asking can we avoid having to do the `foreach` in the following code?  Another way to put it is I'm asking if tail-call optimization is possible in C# coroutines.

```
    private IEnumerable<int> Follow(int source)
    {
        if (source == 0)
            yield break;
        else
        {
            int target = PickTarget(links[source]);

            yield return target;

            // What I'd like to do (doesn't compile):
            //return Follow(target)); 

            // What I seemingly have to do:
            foreach (var next in Follow(target))
                yield return next;
        }
    }
```

A concern is the big-O complexity of that recursive foreach.  Isn't it `O(n) = n + (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ...` ?

Comment: _"Another way to put it is I'm asking if tail-call optimization is possible in C# coroutines."_ - in short, no: https://stackoverflow.com/q/491376/159145 https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2191

Answer (score 3):

I realized the obvious solution is to just rewrite the function to not be recursive.

In the context of a coroutine and given the language constraints, writing it in an imperative rather than functional style leads to a shorter (and perhaps clearer) expression of the algorithm.

```
    private IEnumerable<int> Follow(int source)
    {
        int node = source;

        while (node != 0)
        {
            yield return node;
            node = PickTarget(links[node]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is better than your original solution, if you don't have to use recursion don't use it - it takes resources because it is heavy on the stack