# How to pass F# a string and get the result back in c#

Tags: f#

I am SQL developer and am really new to both F# and C#. I need help on how to pass a string to f# function below and to return the result from F# to C#.

**Description of project:**
I am using stanford postagger to tag a sentence with the parts of speech. 
Reference link from where i copied this code.
(http://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordPOSTagger.html)

```
module File1


open java.io
open java.util
open edu.stanford.nlp.ling
open edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent

// Path to the folder with models

let modelsDirectry = 
__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__  + @'..\stanford-postagger-2013-06-20\models\'

// Loading POS Tagger

let tagger = MaxentTagger(modelsDirectry + 'wsj-0-18-bidirectional-nodistsim.tagger')

let tagTexrFromReader (reader:Reader) = 
let sentances = MaxentTagger.tokenizeText(reader).toArray()

sentances |> Seq.iter (fun sentence ->
    let taggedSentence = tagger.tagSentence(sentence :?> ArrayList)
    printfn "%O" (Sentence.listToString(taggedSentence, false))
)


// Text for tagging

let text = System.Console.ReadLine();

tagTexrFromReader <| new StringReader(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

it won't matter if C# or F# - do make a function that gets a `string` and returns ... let
s say an `int`, you just need something like this (put it in some `MyModule.fs`):

```
namespace MyNamespace

module MyModule =

   // this is your function with one argument (a string named input) and result of int
   let myFun (input : string) : int =
      // do whatever you have to
      5 // the value of the last line will be your result - in this case a integer 5
```

call it in from C#/.net with

```
int result = MyNamespace.MyModule.myFun ("Hallo");
```

I hope this helps you out a bit

For your *example* this would be:

```
let myFun (text : string) =
   use reader = new StringReader(text)
   tagTexrFromReader reader
```

as you'll have this in the module `File1` you can just call it with `var res = Fiel1.myFun(text);`

BTW: `use` is in there because `StringReader` is `IDisposable` and using `use` F# will dispose the object when you exit the scope.

PS: is `tagTexrFromReader` a typo?

Comment: Hi Carsten, Thank you for the quick reply. I tried coding the same in the above file1 module but ended up with errors. It would be great if you can please provide me a code that fits in module file1 mentioned above. Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: what are the errors? the only **magic** is the `let myFun input = output` - you just have somthing similar into your module. I would give a direct translation but I cannot see what you are really trying to return

Comment: Sorry Carsten, I should have given you details about what i need exactly. I need to pass the variable text123 from c# to tagTexrFromReader <| new StringReader(text123) and needed the output Sentence.listToString(taggedSentence, false) returned to c#..

Comment: @user3898531 It appears you are starting with no knowledge of how to do C#/F# interop.  You will probably be better off finding a blog post or tutorial on how to do that rather than asking questions on SO.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478531/call-f-code-from-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks Carsten for your help..i understand as the questions im asking are of basic category..